# Automatically re-run rspec example if a Timeout::Error occurs

Tags: rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

First of all I agree that mocking external API calls is the right thing to do most of the times. However not in this case.

I'm getting random `Timeout::Error` exceptions in some of my tests and I would like to be able to ignore them and automatically re-run the example. Failure should be reported only after 10 unsuccessful attempts.

Any other exceptions & failures should be reported.

I've tried to implement this behavior using a global `around(:each)` hook in `spec/spec_helper.rb` file:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    attempts = 0
    passed = false

    begin
      attempts +=1
      example.run
      passed = true

    rescue Timeout::Error => e
      raise e if attempts >= 10

    end until passed
  end
end
```

However the rescue part never gets executed when an exception occurs. Any idea why?

Thanks!
Dorian

P.S. I'm using rspec 2.6.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot rescue exceptions in `around` blocks because they do not propagate. However, if you absolutely *must* re-run failing examples, you can pry the current exception out of `@example`, like here:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/c21d5eb2375b610ac13f54cf240e59c80918a2f1/spec/spec_helper.rb#L16

It looks pretty nasty. Our excuse was a bug in our upstream library, but I would generally avoid this if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

We used the @Jo's answer as a way to access an exception for logging.

It worked great for us until we upgraded RSpec to 2.99 (with a view to moving to 3.0). It seems the instance variable *@exception* is no longer present on the *example* object in an around hook.

We had to switch to a before and after hook, and access the exception as before from the after hook's *example*.

```
config.after(:each) do |example|
    exception = example.instance_variable_get('@exception')
    # ....
end
```

We weren't trying to do a retry though, I am not sure how you would achieve that in RSpec 3.0.